# why footer is re-positioning after page slide

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple page with fixed header and footer. When it Slides from page1 to page2, the footer on page is first shown at the position where the content of page2 is ended (somewhat middle) then after page finish sliding the footer re-position itself and move to bottom. Is there any way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: That's really odd... i have never seen anything like that happen before.

Comment: its only when u r loading a page very first time.

Answer (score 0):

In the `pageshow` event handler of the second page you can try adding the following code snippet:

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars.show(true);
```

Comment: the toolbars are not hidden, it just re-positioned

Comment: Even if it is repositioned,this code would immediately position it to the bottom.If you can post a sample code where this issue can be reproduced I will take a look into it.

Comment: you would need to find a way to override the footer being hidden in the first place, because hiding it pushes it to the middle of the page. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in JQM. It happens when the page content is shorter than the screen size.

My educated guess, why it happens:

- After transitions, JQM triggers **updateLayout**, which recalculates footer position by hiding-recalulate-showing
- Toolbars are hidden using CSS:top property and setting it to 0
  So on a long page, to hide the footer CSS:top is set to **0**, pushing your footer down to where it would be in a static page flow = the end of your document.
- To show the footer, JQM calculates, where you are on your page vs. your screen size and footer height and comes up with some CSS:top = -12345px. Check CSS-top in Firebug when the footer is visible.

= to hide: CSS-top = 0
= to show: CSS-top = -1234px

Now if your **page is shorter than the screen height** (screen 600px, page 200px for example), hiding the footer by setting CSS:top=0 will stick it to the end of the page, which is right in the middle of your screen at 200px.

Since **updateLayout** recalculates footer position, it is hidden-recalculated-shown. And there you have your jumping footer.

I've done a fix with pull request on Github - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/3050.

I guess since the toolbars will switch to pos:fixed with JQM 1.1. nobody bothered to pull it in any more. But it work nevertheless.